# bash - count files per directory and total at the end

Tags: linux, bash, find

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with bash 4.4.20

I am trying to count the number of files in each directory starting in the directory where I executed the script.  Borrowing from other coders, I found this script and modified it.  I am trying to modify it to provide a total at the end, but I can't seem to get it.  Also, the script is running the same count function twice each loop and that is inefficient.  I inserted that extra find command because I could not get the results of the nested '**find | wc -l**' to store in a variable.  And it still didn't work.

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sort -n | while read dir; do
  printf "%-25.25s : " "$dir"
  find "$dir" -type f | wc -l
  filesthisdir=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)
  count=$count+$filesthisdir
done

echo "Total files : $count"
```

Here are the results.  It should total up the results.  Otherwise, this would work well.

```
./1800wls1                : 1086
./1800wls2                : 1154
./1900wls-in1             : 780
./1900wls-in2             : 395
./1900wls-in3             : 0
./1900wls-out1            : 8
./1900wls-out2            : 304
./1900wls-out3            : 160
./test                    : 0
Total files : 0
```

Comment: Specifying `min` and `max` to 1 implies you do not really need `find`

Comment: @Jetchisel How can you loop over the directories without parsing `ls` ?

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob; for d in */; do array=("$d"/*); echo "${#array[@]}"; done` ?

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `while` loop is executed in a sub shell. By using `<<<` you make sure it's executed in the current shell.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while read dir; do
  printf "%-25.25s : " "$dir"
  find "$dir" -type f | wc -l
  filesthisdir=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)
  ((count+=filesthisdir))
done <<< "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sort -n)"

echo "Total files : $count"
```

Of course you also can make use of a for loop:

```sh
for i in "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sort -n)"; do
  # do something
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `(( count += filesthisdir))` and think about counting files with newlines.
You should change your find command:

```
filesthisdir=$(find "$dir" -type f -exec echo . \;| wc -l)
```